# Phoenix - return Ecto query results to a specific client

Tags: elixir, ecto, channel, phoenix-channels

I'm currently trying to devise a scheme where the following happens.

Client `A` is subscribed/connected to topic/channel `T`.

`A` sends a message in the form of a `select` query to `T`.

Only `A` receives the query results, no other subscribers.

Is this even possible using Channels? The main reason I chose Channels was for the excellent websocket support - however I'm open to other Phoenix solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Channels should do the work you want. You can push the query results down to the user who sent the query using `push`:

```
def handle_in("new_query", %{"query" => query}, socket) do

    # do the query and store the result into query_result

    #return back the result using push to the user
    push socket, "new_query", %{query_result: query_result}
    {:ok, socket}
end
```

If you want to return the query result to all users who are joined to the topic, you can simply use `broadcast` instead of `push`, see the docs [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#content)